# Jetpack Compose: Correct way to let a usr edit a text value contained in a StateFlow object

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack

I have a ViewModel containing a MutableStateFlow called `uiState`.

The uiState contains a string value called `myString` which is originally initialised from a repository ( remote API), but then should be editable by the user. Whenever the user edits it, it should be saved back to the repository.

```
class MyViewModel {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MyUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<MyUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
}
```

My understanding is that you should not directly connect a StateFlow value `uiState.myString` to a OutlinedTextField.  For example, this is clearly stated in this blog post here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5

So what is the correct approach to achieve the desired behaviour?

Here is what I am currently thinking of, but I have no idea if that's a good idea:

Inside the Compose function, define a local string variable that is originally initialised by the value of `uiState.myString`, and then, when the input is complete, update first the repository and then `uiState.myString`.

```
@Composable
fun MyTextEdit(
    initialValue: String // this arguments gets passed `uiState.myString` when
    onKeyboardDone: () -> Unit,
) {
    val editString: String = remember { mutableStateOf(default= initialValue) }
    OutlinedTextField(
    value = editString,
    onValueChange = { newValue => editString = newValue} 
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = { saveToRegistryAndThenUpdateMyStringInUiState() }
    )

[...]
// And then the composable is called like this:

@Composable
fun MyUi(
    val uiState by MyViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    MyTextEdit(
        initialValue=uiState.myString,
        onKeyboardDone = { newValue ->
              saveToRepository(newValue){ 
                    savedValue -> uiState.update {
                        currentState ->
                        currentState.copy(myString = newValue)
                    }
              }
         }
)
```

Will this work? Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to save `newValue` after some delay in repository whenever user inputs value instead of depending on keyboard's `onDone` action.

For `delay` - you can use  [`debounce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html)

Here is basic example:

```
ViewModel
```

```
const val DEBOUNCE_DELAY = 600L

val newValue = MutableStateFlow("")

init {
    // This will be called at delay of 600MS whenever `newValue` is updated
    viewModelScope.launch {
        newValue.debounce {
            if (it.isEmpty()) 0 else DEBOUNCE_DELAY
        }.flowOn(appDispatcher.IO)
            .collectLatest { newStr ->
                if (newStr.isNotEmpty()) {
                    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
                            // Save newValue to repository & state
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


fun onValueChange(newStr: String) {
    newValue.value = newStr
}
```

```
In View
```

```
@Composable
fun MyTextEdit(
    initialValue: String // this arguments gets passed `uiState.myString` when
    onKeyboardDone: () -> Unit,
) {
    val editString: String = remember { mutableStateOf(default= initialValue) }
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = editString,
        onValueChange = { newValue => MyViewModel.onValueChanged(newValue) } 
    )

[...]
```

Comment: If you really need to validate the input you must use SharedFlow rather using StateFlow.

Answer (score 0):

For the best `TextField` Best practices you can directly use `mutableStateOf` inside the `ViewModel` and **ViewModel will keep track of it when configuration changes**.

1. You can define a **Text** variable inside the ViewModel and get it Inside the screen.
2. Make a function which will update the String value in ViewModel.

**Stack07ViewModel.kt**

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class Stack07ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var textFieldValue by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    fun updateTextField(str: String) {
        textFieldValue = str
    }
}
```

**You can use in your screen as below**

> We are passing the initial value from the `ViewModel` and whenever
> `TextField` value changes we call `updateTextField` function in `ViewModel`.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.md.newcomposeplayground.stackoverflowq.viewmodels.Stack07ViewModel

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Stack07(stack07ViewModel: Stack07ViewModel) {

    Scaffold (
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Text(text = "Text Field Demo")
            },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                ))
        }
    ){
        Column (modifier = Modifier
            .padding(it)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)){
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                value = stack07ViewModel.textFieldValue,
                onValueChange = {
                    stack07ViewModel.updateTextField(it)
                },
                placeholder = {
                    Text(text = "Enter your text")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I shouldn't be using a MutableStateFlow at all? Just load and save data directly inside a textFieldValue by mutableStateOf("")?

Comment: Yes this is the best practices if you would like to follow

Comment: Read more https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5

Comment: Yea, I read that.... the messaging seems inconsistent...  on the one hand, they want you to use StateFlow, on the other Hand, they warn you against using it with text fields... it seems like Google isn't so sure about what to do either?